# Json mapping works for keys but not values

Tags: c#, json

my json mapping whose format is given below works for the keys but not for the values (nothing is displayed or sometimes NULL), if you have an idea it would help me a lot.

```json
{"0": [{"agents": true, "hv": true, "pos": [8, 7]}, {"agents": true, "hv": true, "pos": [1, 9]}, {"agents": true, "hv": true, "pos": [6, 5]}, {"agents": true, "hv": true, "pos": [4, 1]}, {"agents": true, "hv": true, "pos": [1, 4]}, {"agents": true, "hv": true, "pos": [2, 2]}, {"agents": false, "hv": false, "pos": [1, 6]}, {"agents": false, "hv": false, "pos": [5, 2]}, {"agents": false, "hv": false, "pos": [9, 5]}, {"agents": false, "hv": false, "pos": [8, 5]}, {"agents": false, "hv": true, "pos": [3, 6]}, {"agents": false, "hv": true, "pos": [8, 9]}], "1": [{"agents": true, "hv": true, "pos": [7, 7]}, {"agents": true, "hv": true, "pos": [1, 8]}, {"agents": true, "hv": true, "pos": [6, 5]}, {"agents": true, "hv": true, "pos": [4, 1]}, {"agents": true, "hv": true, "pos": [1, 4]}, {"agents": true, "hv": true, "pos": [2, 1]}, {"agents": false, "hv": false, "pos": [1, 6]}, {"agents": false, "hv": false, "pos": [5, 2]}, {"agents": false, "hv": false, "pos": [9, 5]}, {"agents": false, "hv": false, "pos": [8, 5]}, {"agents": false, "hv": true, "pos": [4, 6]}, {"agents": false, "hv": true, "pos": [9, 9]}]}
```

```cs
public class Agent
{
    public bool isAgent { get; set; }
    public bool hasHV { get; set; }
    public int[] position { get; set; }
}`

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class JSONReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset textJson;
    Dictionary<string, Agent[]> agentMap = new Dictionary<string, Agent[]>();

    private void Start()
    {
        agentMap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Agent[]>>(textJson.text);
        print(agentMap);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Agent[]> entry in agentMap)
        {
            print("Key = "+entry.Key);
             Agent[] agents = entry.Value;
            foreach (Agent agent in agents)
            {
                print("Value = "+agent.position);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text not as images

Comment: It's done, sorry I didn't know ^^

Comment: Unless the names match, you have to specify name resolution manually via attributes. I suggest you just rename you class properties appropriately: `class Agent { public bool IsAgent { get; set; } public bool Hv { get; set; } public int[] Pos { get; set; } } `

Comment: Indeed now it works, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As **Aluan Haddad** had pointed out Use `pos` instead of `position`

```
public class Agent
{
  public bool isAgent { get; set; }
  public bool hasHV { get; set; }
  public int[] pos { get; set; }
}
```